# Accumulate Strings in Loop and Print Out all of them

Tags: java, string

I am trying to figure out how to accumulate user inputs in for loop and then to print them out with one system.out.print. This is my test code for the problem. 
So for example if a user type : Mike for his name and Joe,Jack,Dave for other names, how to print them all just having one variable because amount of variables are not known since a user has that decision. Also is it possible to do that without stringbuilder and without arrays?

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Accumulate {

public static void main(String[] args) {
String othernames = " ",name;
int count,n;
Scanner kybrd = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Enter your name ");
name = kybrd.nextLine();
System.out.println("How many other names would you like to add ? ");
count = kybrd.nextInt();
kybrd.nextLine();

for(n=0;n<count;++n){

System.out.println("Enter other names ");
othernames = kybrd.nextLine();



}

System.out.println("Other names are "+othernames + " And your name is "+ name);

}

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can call it recursively, for instance:

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
String s;
while(condition) {
    s = s + sc.nextLine();
}
```

this will always concat the lines you enter, you can also add commas, or spaces, or whatever you want to add.

Comment: I see. It works well. Also with for loop too. I guess with any type of loop would be good. Thank you for your help.

Comment: One more thing. You said i can add commas, spaces and more... Since they are all together now, how to separate them is separate lines ?

Comment: @lvanko in the 4th line add line saparator

Comment: yea, like @igreen said, just add something like this to add a comma on the end of the string, each new string you concat will have comma on it's end:

s = s + sc.nextLine() + ",";

Answer (score 0):

as for your question about using Objects other than `StringBuilder` you can use `List<String>` and build a string for it at the final step. 
you can use `Map<String, String>` if you need more complex data structure.